# Sagemath: Is there a simple way to factor a polynomial over C & have the roots appear in radical instead of decimal form?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, sage

In Mathematica, if I do the following

```
Roots[x^3 - 2 == 0, x]
```

I get

```
x=(-1)^(2/3) 2^(1/3) || x=(-2)^(1/3) || x = 2^(1/3)
```

---

I want to do something similar in Sagemath

```
sage: F1.<x> = PolynomialRing(CC)
sage: f=x^3 - 2
sage: f.roots()
[(1.25992104989487, 1),
 (-0.629960524947437 - 1.09112363597172*I, 1),
 (-0.629960524947437 + 1.09112363597172*I, 1)]
```

Is there a way in sagemath to see it either as radicals or as `^(1/n)` or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you need this computation to take place within a complex polynomial ring? I'm not an expert in computer algebra and I'm sure I'm oversimplifying or something, but I believe that is the root of this behavior; Sage treats the complex numbers as an inexact field, meaning that it stores the coefficients `a` and `b` in `a+b*I` as (default 53-bit) floats rather than as symbolic constants. Basically, what you are asking for is a type error, any object defined over the `ComplexField` (or `ComplexDoubleField`, or presumably any inexact field) will have floats as its coefficients. On the other hand, the corresponding behavior in the symbolic ring (where the token `x` lives by default) seems to be exactly what you are looking for; more specifically, evaluating `var("t"); solve(t^3-2==0,t)` returns `[t == 1/2*I*sqrt(3)*2^(1/3) - 1/2*2^(1/3), t == -1/2*I*sqrt(3)*2^(1/3) - 1/2*2^(1/3), t == 2^(1/3)]`.